# How to return a mutable reference?

Tags: rust

I started to play around with rust, and in one of my tests and did the following code:

```
fn main() {
    match std::io::Command::new("ls").arg("/mnt").output() {
        Ok(o) => println!("ls /mnt:\n{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(o.output.as_slice())),
        Err(e) => fail!("Ops! {}", e),
    };
    match std::io::Command::new("ls").arg("/media").output() {
        Ok(o) => println!("ls /media: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(o.output.as_slice())),
        Err(e) => fail!("Ops! {}", e),
    };
}
```

The code above works fine.

Then I decided to make a function to return the command I am instantiating, since they are so similar. Something like:

```
fn main() {
    match ls("/mnt").output() {
        Ok(o) => println!("ls /mnt:\n{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(o.output.as_slice())),
        Err(e) => fail!("Ops! {}", e),
    };
    match ls("/media").output() {
        Ok(o) => println!("ls /media: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(o.output.as_slice())),
        Err(e) => fail!("Ops! {}", e),
    };
}

fn ls(path: &str) -> &std::io::Command {
    std::io::Command::new("ls").arg(path)
}
```

This one doesn't work.

I got `reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime defined on the block at 12:39 ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 12:39`.

Okay, I guess I got it. The problem is that the lifetime of `arg`'s return is bound to the `ls` function scope hence making the compilation error when returning it (right?).

I tried using a box without success. I believe to make it work I should used a [named lifetime](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-lifetimes.html#named-lifetimes) but I got to be honest that I didn't (yet) get the concept.

**How do I return the `Command` created in `ls` to outside of it's scope?**

I am using rustc 0.12.0. Don't restrain yourself from using C++ *stuff* on your answer, I got some experience on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the command you create is in the scope of `ls()`, you cannot return a reference to it : The command would go out of scope and the reference would be invalid. You have to return the `Command` object itself.

As `.arg(path)` returns a `&mut` reference to your `Command` object, simply don't use its output :

```
fn ls(path: &str) -> std::io::Command {
    let mut cmd = std::io::Command::new("ls");
    cmd.arg(path);
    cmd
}
```

The fact that `arg()` returns a `&mut` reference is only a way to simply chain it, like this :

```
cmd.arg("arg1").arg("arg2").arg("arg3")
```

Comment: that was so simple that I feel kinda stupid :p ty by the way :)

Comment: This took me a ridiculous amount of time to figure out, thank you so much for this! :)

Comment: omg thank you -- so simple I was struggling with this too.  Thank you 6 years later.